# In a stored procedure return the result of an UPDATE with OUTPUT DELETED clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to write a function that increments and returns an int column value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetNextTagSuffix]
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE [MyTable]
    SET [NextTagSuffix] = [NextTagSuffix] + 1
    OUTPUT DELETED.[NextTagSuffix]
    WHERE [MyTableId] = 'SpecialCase'

END
```

The *OUTPUT* clause can output *INTO* a table variable or temp table but I just need that single value so adding it first to a table variable seems silly. Is there any way to assign that value directly to a variable and return it?

RESOLVED using table variable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetNextTagSuffix]
@TagSuffix int out
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @tagTable TABLE
(
  NextTagSuffix int
)

UPDATE [MyTable]
SET [NextTagSuffix] = [NextTagSuffix] + 1
OUTPUT DELETED.[NextTagSuffix] INTO @tagTable
WHERE [MyTableId] = 'SpecialCase'

SET @TagSuffix = (SELECT MAX(NextTagSuffix) FROM @tagTable)

RETURN @TagSuffix

END
```

Comment: While I agree it seems odd, I recommend using a table variable over a temp table.  Temp tables will use tempdb, while table variables will only use tempdb if there's no memory available for the operation -- so table variables are more likely to be faster.  Either alleviates a second read of the table to get the value...  Incidentally, starting in SQL Server 2012 you could use a sequence to handle the increment.

Comment: If you just want to return a single value then you can use Output variables in your stored procedures

Comment: Thanks @OMGPonies - unfortunately I'm stuck with 2005 for the time being.

Comment: fyi: You could change your `SET` statement to `SELECT @TagSuffix = MAX( NextTagSuffix ) FROM @TagTable`.

Comment: @user92546 isn't that just personal preference? Is there any reason to prefer SELECT over SET in this case?

Comment: @DavidClarke - Quite true.  In this case there is no difference.  Some people prefer `SET` to make it clearer that a variable is being affected.  A single `SELECT` can set several variables at once which can be a significant benefit if the query is expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to assign the output to a table variable or temp table.  From [BOL documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx),

```
<OUTPUT_CLAUSE> ::=
{
    [ OUTPUT <dml_select_list> INTO { @table_variable | output_table } [ ( column_list ) ] ]
    [ OUTPUT <dml_select_list> ]
}
```

Note how it specified that the output can be selected into a table variable or table.

In 2006 a [Microsoft Connect action item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/150944/allow-variable-assignment-using-dml-output-clause) was filed requesting exactly the functionality you want to use (the ability to do an assignment to a scalar variable from the results of a OUTPUT clause).  Microsoft closed the item as "Closed as Won't Fix", so for sure this feature was not available in SQL 2005 and was not put into SQL 2008.  So unless they had a change of heart, it is not available in SQL 2012 either.  You might want to up-vote the connect item or file a new one requesting this feature in a future SQL release.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I did read the doco and noted the options for the OUTPUT clause. I was hoping there might have been an alternative to using a table var.

Answer (score 0):

U could however use Output parameter in your SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetNextTagSuffix]
@value int output
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE [MyTable]
SET [NextTagSuffix] = [NextTagSuffix] + 1
OUTPUT DELETED.[NextTagSuffix]
WHERE [MyTableId] = 'SpecialCase'

END


DECLARE @result int 
EXEC GetNextTagSuffix @value=@result output
```